# Is it possible to remove the date from this template?

Tags: titles

Is it possible to remove the date from this template?

**text code:**

```
\documentclass[paper=a4, fontsize=11pt]{scrartcl}   % 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage[ngerman, english]{babel}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[protrusion=true,expansion=true]{microtype}  
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm}                    
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}                           
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{sectsty}                                    
\allsectionsfont{\centering \normalfont\scshape}    
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancyplain}
\fancyhead{}                                            
\fancyfoot[C]{}                                         
\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}                                 
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}          
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}               
\setlength{\headheight}{13.6pt}

\numberwithin{equation}{section}        
\numberwithin{figure}{section}          
\numberwithin{table}{section}               

% Zeilenabstand
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}

\newcommand{\horrule}[1]{\rule{\linewidth}{#1}}     % 
\newcommand{\twoobjects}[2]{%
  \centering \leavevmode\vbox{\hbox{#1}\nointerlineskip\hbox{#2}} %
}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{references.bib}



\title{
        %\vspace{-1in}  
        \usefont{OT1}{bch}{b}{n}
        \normalfont \normalsize \textsc{SmartBusTraffic: Estimation of Bus positions based on Crowd Sourcing Monitoring} \\ [25pt]
        \horrule{0.5pt} \\[0.4cm]
        \huge Handbook
        \horrule{2pt} \\[0.5cm]
}


\begin{document}

\maketitle


Public transit service plays an important ...

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: simply `\date{}`?

Comment: Little hint, the code is using packages that shouldn't be used with KOMA-script. You get corresponding warnings. By the way, why do you call this a *template*?

Comment: also, when posting, please try to minimize the example as much as possible. Many of the packages have nothing to do with the example, and removing them might also show you where the problem lies. This is great for your own learning, but also makes it easier and faster to give answers, as well as for other users to use your example as a general question. have a look at http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that

Comment: @Johannes_B: Thanks it works. I called it a template because I downloaded it as template from somewhere to write first report. Is it possible to move the line up after deleting the date? Please see screenshot above.

Comment: I think using `title` and `maketitle` is the very wrong approach in your case. Just copy the argument of `title` and remove the maketitle command. Instead, use the copied stuff and manual spacing.

Comment: Out of interest, where did you get the template from?

Comment: I think it was from this site http://www.howtotex.com/templates/

Comment: http://www.howtotex.com/templates/template-added-project-report/

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me you don't  want to use `\maketitle` at all, if you are not satisfied with the default (the default assumes that every document has an author and a date). Do the title by yourself.

[image: thebookTitlestuff]

```
\documentclass[paper=a4,
fontsize=11pt,
headlines=1.8,footlines=1.8
]{scrartcl}   % 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage[ngerman, english]{babel}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[protrusion=true,expansion=true]{microtype}  
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm}                    
\usepackage[%pdftex% JB: No option pdftex
]{graphicx}                           
\usepackage{url}
%\usepackage{sectsty}                                    
%\allsectionsfont{\centering \normalfont\scshape}    
\renewcommand{\raggedsection}{\centering}
\setkomafont{disposition}{\normalfont\scshape}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ofoot*{\pagemark}
%\usepackage{fancyhdr}
%\pagestyle{fancyplain}
%\fancyhead{}                                            
%\fancyfoot[C]{}                                         
%\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}                                 
%\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}          
%\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}               
%\setlength{\headheight}{13.6pt}

\numberwithin{equation}{section}        
\numberwithin{figure}{section}          
\numberwithin{table}{section}               

% Zeilenabstand
%\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\linespread{1.5}

\newcommand{\horrule}[1]{\rule{\linewidth}{#1}}%truly horrible
\newcommand{\twoobjects}[2]{%
    \centering \leavevmode\vbox{\hbox{#1}\nointerlineskip\hbox{#2}} %
}
\usepackage{subcaption}




\begin{document}

\begin{center}
%   \usefont{OT1}{bch}{b}{n}% JB: switching to another font
%   \normalfont% JB: switching back to the default right
%   after, do you want this?
%   \normalsize
    \textsc{SmartBusTraffic: Estimation of Bus positions based on Crowd Sourcing Monitoring} \\ [25pt]
    \horrule{0.5pt} \\[0.4cm]
    \huge Handbook
    \horrule{2pt} \\[0.5cm]
\end{center}


Public transit service plays an important \dots

\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

I made a few additional changes to the code.