# center the word as in the title

Tags: titles

I want to move the word up after `\huge`  as in the title in the screenshot below. I am trying to use the stuff in the title argument since I do not want to add a name or date and `\maketitle` generate a big space if I add `\date{}` so I decided to get through with this approach. I will delete `\title{}` and `\maketitle` after managing it.

**code:**

```
\documentclass[paper=a4, fontsize=11pt]{scrartcl}   % 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage[ngerman, english]{babel}
\usepackage[protrusion=true,expansion=true]{microtype}      
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\newcommand{\horrule}[1]{\rule{\linewidth}{#1}}     % 
\newcommand{\twoobjects}[2]{%
  \centering \leavevmode\vbox{\hbox{#1}\nointerlineskip\hbox{#2}} %
}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{references.bib}

\title{
        %\vspace{-1in}  
        \usefont{OT1}{bch}{b}{n}
        \normalfont \normalsize \textsc{SmartBusTraffic: Estimation of Bus positions based on Crowd Sourcing Monitoring} \\ [25pt]
        \horrule{0.5pt} \\[0.4cm]
        \huge Handbook
        \horrule{2pt} \\[0.5cm]
        \date{}
}


\begin{document}

\maketitle

        \begin{center}
                \usefont{OT1}{bch}{b}{n}
        \normalfont \normalsize \textsc{SmartBusTraffic: Estimation of Bus positions based on Crowd Sourcing Monitoring} \\ [25pt]
        \end{center}


        \horrule{0.5pt} \\[0.4cm]
        \begin{center}
        \huge Handbook \\
        \end{center}

        \horrule{2pt} \\[0.5cm]



Public transit service plays an important ...

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please note, that `\\[...]` is always a little bit awkward

Comment: Why didn't you link to the new question in your other one? We could have closed that and i would have saved time. Now we have almost two identical answers two different problems.

Comment: You probably want to add `\noindent` in front of the `\horrule` so that you're not getting a paragraph indentation at that point.  Currently, you are.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `\centering` instead of `\begin{center}...\end{center}`, but use it within a group, i.e. a `{...}` pair, for example. The `center` environment adds some vertical space before and after the centered content.

A. Ellett made a good comment: The blank line (or a `\par`) before closing the group is needed by `\centering`, otherwise there would be no centering (for this effectively one - line text).

```
\documentclass[paper=a4, fontsize=11pt]{scrartcl}   % 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage[ngerman, english]{babel}
\usepackage[protrusion=true,expansion=true]{microtype}      
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\newcommand{\horrule}[1]{\rule{\linewidth}{#1}}     % 

\title{%
  \usefont{OT1}{bch}{b}{n}%
  \normalfont \normalsize \textsc{SmartBusTraffic: Estimation of Bus positions based on Crowd Sourcing Monitoring} \\[25pt]
  \horrule{0.5pt} \\[0.4cm]
  \huge Handbook
  \horrule{2pt} \\[0.5cm]
  \date{}%
}


\begin{document}

\maketitle
\begin{center}
  \usefont{OT1}{bch}{b}{n}
  \normalfont \normalsize \textsc{SmartBusTraffic: Estimation of Bus positions based on Crowd Sourcing Monitoring} \\ [25pt]
\end{center}


\horrule{0.5pt} %\\[0.4cm]
{
  \centering
  \huge Handbook

}
\horrule{2pt} \\[0.5cm]
Public transit service plays an important ...


\end{document}
```

Comment: Just wondering, would you get the same effect by using centering as an environment?

Comment: @daleif: You mean `\begin{centering}...`? I never use macros as environments

Comment: I do sometimes as it provides better structure, not sure if there is a down side

Comment: @daleif: I don't expect a down side here for `\begin{centering}` since it does not add spacing. But it's still no group, or is it?

Comment: That is the point of using it, begin/end already includes the grouping. My main way of using it is wrapping an align in allowdisplaybreaks as an localized environment

Comment: @daleif: Ah, I thought the grouping comes in only for 'real' environment

Comment: Define real environment. You do not need newenvironment to defined an environment, and the endenv does not even need to be defined.

Comment: @daleif: True. Most times it's `\def\endfoo` ;-)

Comment: You have to, newcommand will not allow you to define macros starting with end

Comment: @daleif: I know, I've asked a question here about one year ago about `\end...` stuff macros defined with `\newcommand`

Comment: [Is it possible to remove the date from this template?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/284570)

Comment: It would probably be a good idea to explain why you left the blank line before closing the group for centering.  I think this is a point newbies may not grasp.

Comment: @A.Ellett: Thanks for your comment. I added a small explanation.